# Consuming .asmx or ?WSDL using dart program

Tags: .net, wsdl, dart, asmx

hi i want to connect my dart program to .net web service.

I have ?WSDL url and have to connect my dart program or consume this ?WSDL link in my program

Can any one please explain how can i do this if my question is wrong please correct me.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';


void main(){
  Uri u  =Uri.parse('https://mydomain.net/myDart.asmx?WSDL');


    print(u.query);
 var c = u.query;
 print(c);
  window.sessionStorage ['par']= '${c}';
  querySelector('#ravi').text =  '${c}';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen anything along those lines for Dart yet.

Comment: have you stumbled upon anything like this in the last year?  Have some legacy soap services to deal with ;)